# JavaScriptからファイルをダウンロードさせるのはどうしたら良いですか？

Tags: javascript

ブラウザーでダウンロードリンクを踏んだときのようにJavaScriptからファイルをダウンロードさせたいのですが、どのようにしたら良いでしょうか？

```
$.getJSON('/data.json', function(data) {
  // ファイルダイアログを表示して、指定したファイルへ data を書き込む
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`content`を`fileName`でダンロードしたい場合の実装
`content`は生の文字列

```
var downloadAsFile = function(fileName, content) {
    var blob = new Blob([content]);
    var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var blobURL = url.createObjectURL(blob);

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = fileName;
    a.href = blobURL;
    a.click();  
};
```

コレでも可

```
var downloadAsFile = function(fileName, content) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = fileName;
    a.href = 'data:application/octet-stream,'+encodeURIComponent(content);
    a.click();
};
```