# CSVファイルをダウンロードしたい

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> download() throws IOException {
    HttpHeaders h = new HttpHeaders();
    h.add("Content-Type", "text/csv; charset=MS932");
    h.setContentDispositionFormData("filename", "hoge.csv");
    return new ResponseEntity<>("あ,い,う,え,お".getBytes("MS932"), h, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

http://blog.okazuki.jp/entry/2015/07/18/220959
上記サイト様を見ますと、これでCSVファイルをダウンロードできるようにうかがえますが、
new ResponseEntity<>("あ,い,う,え,お".getBytes("MS932"), h, HttpStatus.OK)
上記の時点で、"あ,い,う,え,お"を書き込んだ"hoge.csv"というファイルをローカル（Windowsのダウンロードディレクトリなど）
にダウンロードするということなのでしょうか。

試しに上記をjavascriptで呼んでみたのですが、
結果ブラウザに"あ,い,う,え,お"と表示されるのみとなりました。
CSVファイルなどをローカルにダウンロードする場合どのようにすべきなのでしょうか。

javascript側

```
  $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"/download",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "html"
    }).done(function(responseData, status, jqXHR) {
    }).fail(function(responseError, status, errorThrown) {
    });
```

Comment: Spring Bootは、Javaのフレームワークです。JavaであればPCのファイルを読み書きできます。　Javascriptは、PCのファイルの読み書きができません。　JavaとJavascriptは言語が似ているだけで、全く別のものですよ。

Comment: 通常は、DBから取得したデータなどをjavascript側をPOSTしてjava側でダウンロードする感じなのでしょうか。FileInputStreamなどでファイルを作成するのかと思いますが、WEBからファイルを保存する場合、パスなどは指定しなくていいのでしょうか？いまいちその辺がつかめず、四苦八苦しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ファイルがダウンロードできるかどうか確認したい、ということであれば、Webブラウザで
http://localhost:8080/download (※デフォルト設定の場合)
へアクセスすれば良いです。

Javascriptを利用してダウンロードしたい、ということであれば、例えば

- [javascript - JavaScriptからファイルをダウンロードさせるのはどうしたら良いですか？ - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/302/2808)

に書かれているような形で可能でしょう。

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/download', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var blob = new Blob([this.response]);
    var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var blobURL = url.createObjectURL(blob);

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = "hoge.csv";
    a.href = blobURL;
    a.click();  
};

xhr.send();
```

その他参考:

- [Javascript to csv export encoding issue - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19492846/4506703)
- [バイナリファイルをAjaxで取得する際に注意する点 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/tom_konda/items/484955b8332e0305ebc4)

Comment: 本題とは関係ないのでここに記載しますが、ExcelでもUTF-8形式のファイルは開けるようですので([参考](http://qiita.com/wadahiro/items/eb50ac6bbe2e18cf8813#%E3%81%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%91-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%82%92%E5%90%AB%E3%82%80csv%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E3%83%80%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89))、MS932でなくUTF-8を使う方が全体的には楽になるのではと感じました。

Comment: yukihaneさま、かいとうありがとうございます！さっそくためいしてみたところ、正常にダウンロードが可能でした。通常、WEBからダウンロードする場合はjavascript側から行うのが普通なのでしょうか。もう少し勉強してみます。

Comment: javascriptでダウンロードするのが普通かどうか、については、どうでしょう…相対的にはjsでダウンロードさせるのは少ないとは思います。ただ、どう実装するかはwebページ作成時の要求に依存する話なので、どちらか一方のみが正しい、ということは無いですね。

Answer (score 0):

Javascript側が、表示するような形でしか処理をしていないからではないでしょうか？取得が出来ているのであれば、Data URI schemeに変換して、そこにページ遷移するような処理にすればダウンロードできるかと思います。
blobに変換する手法などもありますが、こちらはブラウザ次第で動かないことが多いです。

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

```js
function make_downloadlink(){
  var data = "1,2,3,4,5";  
  var edata = encodeURIComponent(data);
  var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + data;
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.setAttribute("href",uri);
  a.setAttribute("download","sample.csv");
  a.innerHTML ='Download';
  document.getElementById("button").appendChild(a);
}

make_downloadlink();
```

```html
<div id="button"></div>
```

Comment: Mononさま、回答ありがとうございます！おっしゃる通り、「Javascript側が、表示するような形でしか処理をしていないからではないでしょうか？」が原因でした。さらに勉強したいと思います！